# How to disable a webpack loader?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to disable the json-loader, that works by default for `webpack >= v2.0.0`. I'm using alot of json files for dev environment and I don't want those to be loaded for the production version. Could anyone suggest how to disable the json-loader of webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You might instruct webpack to process `.json` files with [`null-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/null-loader) instead of the default `json-loader`.

Each imported `.json` will return an empty module.

```
{
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: "null-loader",
},
```